# Batch File That Copies a Line from a Text File and Stores it in a Variable

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file, which I will post below, I am trying to have it copy the first line in a file and then stores it in a variable.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set SEPARATOR=/
set filecontent=
for /f "delims=" %%a in ("MavenInstructions.txt") do (
  set currentline=%%a
  set filecontent=!filecontent!%SEPARATOR%!currentline!
)
echo The file contents are: %filecontent%

echo %filecontent%

pause
```

The first line of the `MavenInstructions.txt` is TEST LINE but what I get when I run my batch file is:

```
The file contents are: /MavenInstructions.txt
/MavenInstructions.txt
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a in ("MavenInstructions.txt") do (
```

`usebackq` is required if the filename is "quoted".

btw -   `set filecontent=!filecontent!%SEPARATOR%%%a`

would suffice.